# How do I stop the call stack from over loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is simple yet infuriating. All I want to do is have an `onClick` event that when triggered changes the state on the component. The only problem is if I don't stop the `addActiveClass` function from running initially with the loaded state prop than I get a call stack overload because this component is being rendered by a `.map` function.

The second I remove the `if (this.state.loaded) { //logic  }` over my state change logic I get

[image]

Please help me understand why I can't do this simple thing in React.

```
class IndividualQA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.addActiveClass = this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
      loaded: false
    };
    // this.state({ arrowState: this.props.arrowClass });
  }
  addActiveClass = (load) => {
    if (this.state.loaded) {
      const currentState = this.state.active;
      console.log(this.state);
      this.setState({ active: !currentState });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xl-11 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-10 col-10">
            {this.props.data.Q}
          </div>
          <div className="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-2 Question">
            <a
              data-toggle="collapse"
              href={`#QA${this.props.id}`}
              id="arrowSVG"
              onClick={this.addActiveClass()}
            >
              <img
                style={{ height: "30px" }}
                className={this.state.active ? "transform" : ""}
                src={downArrow}
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row collapse" id={`QA${this.props.id}`}>
          <div className="col-xl-11 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-11 As-a-long-time-Kiva">
            {this.props.data.A}
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IndividualQA;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in here

```
        <a
          data-toggle="collapse"
          href={`#QA${this.props.id}`}
          id="arrowSVG"
          onClick={this.addActiveClass()} //here
        >
```

This way `addActiveClass` will be called on every render and can cause a infinty loop.

You need to change it to

```
        <a
          data-toggle="collapse"
          href={`#QA${this.props.id}`}
          id="arrowSVG"
          onClick={this.addActiveClass} // without '()'
        >
```

Comment: fuc me i love u

Answer (score 1):

The handler on the a tag should be `this.addActiveClass` not `this.addActiveClass()`